# how to delete the setting of retention.ms from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

by default all topics in our kafka cluster are with retention `hours=24` , ( as defined in kafka server.properties )

we decided to decrease the retention hours only on topic `test` to `64000` ms

so we set the following retention hours - `64000` on topic test

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --entity-type topics --alter --entity-name test -add-config retention.ms=64000
```

now we want to return the default retention hours on topic test ( to `24` hours ) ,as was before

we don't sure if the following kafka cli , really return the retention hours to `24` on topic `test`

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name test --delete-config retention.ms
```

as I know the above delete the configuration of the `retention in ms` but I not sure if this is really what above command is doing

please advice if I am wrong?

NOTE: in order to get all data about retention for particular topic in kafka , we can do

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides
```

reference- [How to see the retention for a particular topic in kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135820/how-to-see-the-retention-for-a-particular-topic-in-kafka)

reference - [Delete topic level config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220849/delete-topic-level-config)

reference - https://gankrin.org/explained-how-to-purge-a-running-kafka-topic/

additionally:

I can suggest other approach as:

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --entity-type topics --alter --entity-name test -add-config retention.ms=86400000
```

its configure the 24 hours for test topic , but this is workaround
but I preferred is to delete the configuration of retention in ms instead of set the retention in ms to `86400000`

Comment: Kafka is not related to Hadoop, so don't need to use that tag... Hard to tell what the problem you're having. Seems you posted a new question and this is working for you?